# Finding Op-Amp Output Resistance using Datasheet

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, resistance

I'm using this [TL071 op-amp datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slos080n/slos080n.pdf) and I am trying to find the op-amp output impedance on the datasheet so I can calculate the output impedance when used in amplifier/peak detector circuit. Do I need to calculate the output impedance from one of the other characteristics on the data sheet or am I missing something?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You really shouldn't be using a 741.

Comment: Sorry, just edited its a TL071, to be used in a peak detector circuit.

Comment: Oh, much better choice.

Comment: You realize that when applied in a closed loop, the output impedance is usually less than an ohm across a broad range of operating frequencies.

Comment: Thank you for all the responses. Yeah I now realise, when implementing it practically, I shouldn't consider it too much - thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't find it if it's not explicitly listed  (which is rare). Typically Zo of the order of a hundred ohms for that type of op-amp.

Closed loop output impedance, of course, is almost zero.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, Sir.

Answer (score 0):

The output impedance in a closed loop situation will increase with frequency because as frequency increases the feedback reduces. The feedback factor in an amplifier, for instance, is equal to 1 + BAo and as frequency increases, the open loop gain,Ao rolls off.
You could say that the output impedance is simulating an inductance which also has an increasing impedance with frequency.